# Error handling in Powershell functions

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I'm trying to modify a script I wrote, to be modular, while I learn more about tool making. I'm at the point where I'm trying to make it handle errors and don't know how to get the functions to break out. Here's what I've got:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [string]$DPMServerName = 'server1'
)

Function Get-Libraries {
    Write-Verbose ("Getting list of libraries connected to {0}." -f $DPMServerName)
    Try {
       Set-Variable -Name libraries -Value (Get-DPMLibrary $DPMServerName -ErrorAction Stop | Where {$_.IsOffline -eq $False})
    }
    Catch [Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.Utils.DlsException] {
        Write-Error ("Cannot connect to the DPM library. It appears that the servername is not valid. The specific error message is: {0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
        Return $_.Exception.Message
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Error ("Unknown error getting library. The specific error message is: {0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
        Return
    }

    Foreach ($library in $libraries) {
        Write-Verbose ("Starting fast inventory on {0}" -f $library)
        Start-DPMLibraryInventory -DPMLibrary $library -FastInventory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    $libraries
}

Function Update-TapeStatus ($libs) { <### add parameter "$libs" to the function ###>
    Foreach ($library in $libs) {
        $tapes = Get-DPMTape -DPMLibrary $library | Where {$_.Location -notmatch "*slot*"} | Sort Location
        <### output the list of tapes ###>
        $tapes
    }
}

$liblist = Get-Libraries
If ($LASTEXITCODE) { 
    Write-Output $LASTEXITCODE
}
Else {
    Update-TapeStatus $liblist
}
```

If there is an error (e.g. getting the list of libraries), I want to present a custom message and stop the script. I'll want to do something similar for other functions. The way it is written though, I'm not getting the desired message.

How to do make this work? Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual behavior you are seeing?  Are you seeing a PowerShell error record, or are you seeing nothing?

Comment: I get the Powershell error: Unable to find type [Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.Utils.DlsException]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, what is when an exception is thrown, PowerShell is trying to match the exception's type with what you specify in the catch clause.

I don't have any experience with the DPM module/snap-in, but I am wondering if the module actually loads the assembly containing the exception type you are trying to catch into the app domain.  By the error you are getting, it does not appear to.  Hopefully you know what the assembly name that contains this class is. Use the `Add-Type` cmdlet with the `-AssemblyName` parameter at the top of your script to load the assembly, so that the PowerShell runtime knows about the exception type you are looking for.

As a last note, it is probably not a good idea to use a class in a Microsoft.Internal namespace as it is not meant for use directly in code, but as support behind the scenes in teh .Net libraries.  Microsoft could pull the rug out from under you with no warning.

Comment: I know why the command fails (the required module is not installed on this machine). What I don't know is how to get that error message out of the function and handle it.

Comment: Instead of using return in your catch blocks, you can use `throw` and catch the exception at the script level in a try/catch statement.  If you use throw by itself, or `throw $_`, you rethrow the original error record/exception. You can throw a string however, so you could do something like ` throw "Cannot connect to the DPM library. It appears that the servername is not valid. The specific error message is: {0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)` and then wrap the `$liblist = Get-Libraries` line in a try/catch statement

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Here's what I've got now (removed the bits that don't apply to this example): `

    Function Get-Libraries {
        Write-Verbose ("Getting list of libraries")
        Try {
           Get-DPMLibrary $DPMServerName -ErrorAction Stop | Where {$_.IsOffline -eq $False}
        }
        Catch {
            Throw ("Cannot connect to the DPM library. Error is: {0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)        
        }

        }

        $libraries
    }

    Try {
        $liblist = Get-Libraries
    }
    Catch {
        write-error $_
        Exit
    }`